# Run Time Check failure #2:

Tags: c++

Below is my code so far. I am just doing this step by step, for a class assignment. Trying not to give the whole code I just want to know what is wrong with what I have so I can learn to fix it. Thanks for the help.

The goal is to create class driver then to get total lap times, compare them and put them in order of 1st thru 3rd place. I've made this in a simple program already. Now I am trying to make an array of the class driver.

So far this is working, It asks for input correctly, and gives an output but before the end of the program I get:

Debug Error!

Run Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'driver' was corrupted.

None of the answers I've found here make sense to my application. I have 0 failures when I run the build before running the program.

I also know not to use single character variables, I just do this as I learn what I'm missing and later change them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Driver
{
int carNumber;

public:
void setNumber(int number)
{
    carNumber = number;
}

int getNumber()
{
    return carNumber;
}

};

int main()
{
int x;
int i;
Driver driver[3];

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Driver " << i << "'s car number: ";
    cin >> x;
    driver[i].setNumber(x);

}
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
cout << "driver " << i << "'s number is " << driver[i].getNumber() <<  endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start for loop as shown below because as we know that array stores n elements from location 0 to n-1.

```
    for (i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
    cout << "Enter Driver " << i << "'s car number: ";
    cin >> x;
     driver[i].setNumber(x);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array access indexes are wrong.

Arrays start at index 0, not 1, and end at 1 less than the number of elements. So for a declaration of `driver[3]`, the valid indexes are 0, 1, and 2, not 1, 2 and 3. With the wrong indexes, you're writing past the end of the array, causing the stack corruption.

Your write loop should be more like

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Driver " << i << "'s car number: ";
    cin >> x;
    driver[i].setNumber(x);

}
```

You'll need to make a similar fix to the read loop.

Comment: Thanks! I think I had that at one time and changed it to get the output different.